# How can I wrap an emitter.on(eventName)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
myEmitter.on('event', (a) => {
  console.log('an event occurred! ' + a);
});
myEmitter.emit('event', "a");
```

How can I change

```
myEmitter.on('event', (a) => {
   console.log('an event occurred! ' + a);
});
```

to something like

```
onEvent((a) => console.log('an event occurred! ' + a))
```

I want to have a wrapper around the myEmitter.on('event'), so my onEvent is essentially just calling myEmitter.on('event'). Is this even possible?

Comment: This can work only if the callback function returns some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const onEvent = cb => myEmitter.on('event', cb);
```

You can also do the following if you want to handle different events:

```
const on = (event, cb) => myEmitter.on(event, cb);
on('event', () => console.log('an event occurred!'));
```

Comment: what if the callback has a parameter?

Comment: Use them in the callback: `(arg1, arg2) => console.log(arg1)`, whatever is passed on emit, will be available in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
const onEvent = (callback) => {
  myEmitter.on('event', callback);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom event something like this.

```
var createEvent = (eventName)=>(callback)=>myEmitter.on(eventName, callback);
let event1 = createEvent('event1');
event1((a)=>{
   console.log('Event Occurred!', a);
});
```